# ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find avd.ini

Tags: android, visual-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have install VS2017 enterprise editon and my Windows version is 7 - 64Bit and my avd name is kl866
when I try to start the emulator I get this following error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'kl866'
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [kl866], use -list-avds to see valid list.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find kl866.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```